# Dell Vostro 15 7510 fan noise issue

Tags: 22.04, 21.10, fan, 21.04, dell-vostro

Dell Vostro 15 7510 : Intel Core i7-11800H (Intel Graphics UHD Xe 11th Gen) + Nvidia Geforce RTX 3050 Ti.

Depending on the Ubuntu version, there is an issue with the fans, though I'm doing nothing (idle state). The CPU/GPU temperatures are between 30 and 60 degrees max.

Observations:

- Windows 11: the fans are quiet.
- Ubuntu 21.04 Live session: the fans are constantly running.
- Ubuntu 21.10 Live session: the fans are quiet (no issue).
- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Live session: the fans are constantly running (issue is back).
- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Live session: the fans are quiet again (no issue).

May I know what parameter / configuration / driver or firmware is set by Ubuntu in the kernel configuration or boot process to get the fans managed by the OS instead of Dell's UEFI BIOS ?
The fans get quiet during Ubuntu 21.10 and 22.04.1 LTS live sessions boot process before showing the Ubiquity menu.

Depending on the version, the issue is either fixed or back.
Knowing what to do could let us fix the issue in case it would show up in the next version(s).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a Dell Inspiron 15 7510 running Manjaro with hybrid graphic drivers. Fans were always on on AC, making a lot of noise.

I solved the problem by installing [TLP](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tlp) and [TLP UI](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tlp_ui) and enabling RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC (under PCIe menu)

[RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwpOh.png)

https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/powercon.html#fan-noise-on-ac-power

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Thermald didn't but TLP does. I followed the instructions to start it correctly. At first the fans were keeping running. Then I changed the option with "Powersave" value instead of "Default", then saved it and restarted TLP and voilà, it stops the fans completely. I hope the fans will run when the CPU charge goes up.